# Inverse of this matrix with trigonometric functions

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, inverse

As part of another question I asked here, the answer was to invert a matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\varphi &\sin\varphi \\
-\rho\sin\varphi &\sin\varphi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I tried inversing the matrix by the formula
$$
\frac{1}{\text{det}}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix},
$$
but with my determinant computed to $1/(\cos\varphi\sin\varphi + \rho\sin²\varphi)$ I get this matrix:
$$
\dfrac{1}{\cos\varphi\sin\varphi + \rho\sin²\varphi}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\varphi & -\sin\varphi \\
\rho\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
And I've looked at trig identities if there is some trick I can do, but I really don't get it. How do you get the inverse matrix to be
$$
\frac{1}{\rho}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho\cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi\\
\rho\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi
\end{bmatrix}?
$$
Which I was told it should be.

### edit (solved)

I had made a mistake (pointed out in comments) when I wrote the matrix, it should have been
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\varphi &\sin\varphi\\
-\rho\sin\varphi &\rho\cos\varphi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that makes the determinant  $\rho$ which makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: I think it should be $\rho \sin^2 (x)$ instead of $\sin^2 (x)$.

Comment: yes, fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the proposed question does not seem correct. Perhaps the bottom-right entry of the first matrix has the value $\rho cos(\phi))$ instead of $sin(\phi)$?

Comment: If i compute the top right most element in the product of the claimed inverse i get: $\cos \phi \sin \phi - \sin^2 \phi / \rho$ so I dont believe they are inverses

Comment: wow! You are right... it should indeed be $\rho\cos\varphi$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\varphi&\sin\varphi\\-\rho\sin\varphi&\sin\varphi\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\neq\frac1\rho\begin{bmatrix}\rho\cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi\\\rho\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi\end{bmatrix}.$$For instance,$$\det\begin{bmatrix}\cos\varphi&\sin\varphi\\-\rho\sin\varphi&\sin\varphi\end{bmatrix}=\cos\varphi\sin\varphi+\rho\sin^2\varphi,$$whereas$$\det\left(\frac1\rho\begin{bmatrix}\rho\cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi\\\rho\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi\end{bmatrix}\right)=\frac1\rho.$$In order to be the inverse of each other, the determinant of the first matrix should be the inverse of the determinant of the second one.

Comment: Could be good to point out that determinant being inverses to each other is required but not always sufficient.